# Flask / Jinja - render user input jinja template inside parent template with scope/context from parent

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

The title is a mess, so let me be as clear as possible. How can I implement `do_magic`?

**In this template.html**

```
{% set x = 1 %}
{{ do_magic(subtemplate) }}, {{ x }}, {{ y }}
```

**Called from this method**

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template(
    'template.html',
    subtemplate='{{ x }}, {{ y }}',
    y=2,
    do_magic=do_magic
  )

def do_magic(some_text):
    ... # what goes here?
```

**Which should output this**

```
1, 2, 1, 2
```

**And NOT this**

```
{{ x }}, {{ y }}, 1, 2
```

Comment: Have you tried `{% include subtemplate %}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe won't that try to include a template by its filename? I need to include from a raw string template, not its filename. And I need to do it from a python function, not from jinja code.

Comment: ...why? Could you give a less abstract example? It seems a bit backwards to pass a function in to get called back with some state from the template and some from the code. What has made this necessary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have the content (subtemplate) stored in my DB. A registered filter (do_magic) wraps the content created in a WYSIWYG editor with a div which has a class that allows a generic script to find the WYSIWYG-created parts of the site and improve some things on it client-side since it would be a pita to do it server-side or in the WYSIWYG editor. Everything works well, except now I want to type the name of a variable in the WYSIWYG editor and get it replaced by a the jinja variable of same name when the page gets rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out!

```
from jinja2 import contextfunction, Markup

@contextfunction
def do_magic(context, subtemplate):
  ''' Renders string subtemplate with variables from the active context. '''
  template_object = app.jinja_env.from_string(subtemplate)
  html = template_object.render(**context)
  return Markup(html)
```

I sure hope this doesn't have some sort of fatal flaw I don't know about.

(btw did you guys see Jinja source code? It builds a python script from the template and then runs the python script!)

### Edit

Turns out ad-hoc WYSIWYG editors don't work well with complex jinja templates, and, thinking back, I don't think I'll ever need a CMS with a bunch of if-else's everywhere.

I guess all I really wanted was the basic templating power of replacing variables. So I made a method to replace the variables using regex instead.

```
import re
from jinja2 import contextfunction, Markup

@contextfunction
def do_magic(context, subtemplate):
  fallback_value = '???'
  def get_replacement(matchobj):
    key = matchobj.group(1)
    return context.get(key, fallback_value)
        
  pattern = r'{{\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*}}'
  html = re.sub(pattern, get_replacement, subtemplate)
  return Markup(html)
```